# Error to install PyTelegramBotAPI in python

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, bots, telegram

im going to create a telegram bot What is the reason for this error when I try to install PytelegramBotAPI in terminal or cmd ?

this is Error
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is
not writeable

thank you ..

Comment: windows or liunx or mac ?

Comment: Also let me know the telegram bot api package ?